# How to sync timestamped animation frames to audio file?

Tags: javascript, audio, synchronization, srt

I have the following code parsing a [demo SRT file](https://github.com/1c7/srt-parser-2/blob/c57ba536057b6c3d3979d468251489f3b3249cb9/test-file/Welcome-648062.en.srt) and printing out the text at the appropriate time, like this:

```
const { default: srtParser2 } = require('srt-parser-2')
const fs = require('fs')

const parser = new srtParser2()

const srtText = fs.readFileSync('ex.srt', 'utf-8')
const chunks = parser.fromSrt(srtText).map(simplify)

animate(chunks)

function animate(chunks) {
  chunks.forEach(({ startms, endms, text }) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.clear()
      console.log(text)
    }, startms)
  })
}

function simplify({ startTime, endTime, text }) {
  let startms = toInterval(startTime)
  let endms = toInterval(endTime)
  return { startms, endms, text }
}

function toInterval(string) {
  const [a, ms] = string.split(',')
  const [h, m, s] = a.split(':')
  const H = parseInt(h, 10) * 1000 * 60 * 60
  const M = parseInt(m, 10) * 1000 * 60
  const S = parseInt(s, 10) * 1000
  const MS = parseInt(ms, 10)
  return H + M + S + MS
}
```

This works fine, when there is no associated audio. But how do I more properly associate this with an audio file in the browser?

Precompiling some of the stuff, essentially what I have now boils down to this (so you can run in the browser):

```js
animate([
  {
    "startms": 50,
    "endms": 2000,
    "text": "- [Adam] Hello, my name is Adam Wilbert,"
  },
  {
    "startms": 2000,
    "endms": 3010,
    "text": "and I'd like to welcome you"
  },
  {
    "startms": 3010,
    "endms": 5040,
    "text": "to Learning Relational Databases."
  },
  {
    "startms": 5040,
    "endms": 7000,
    "text": "In this course, I'm going\nto give you an overview"
  },
  {
    "startms": 7000,
    "endms": 8090,
    "text": "of the planning steps that\nyou should move through"
  },
  {
    "startms": 8090,
    "endms": 11000,
    "text": "before you start development\nin order to ensure"
  },
  {
    "startms": 11000,
    "endms": 13020,
    "text": "that your system works as expected."
  },
  {
    "startms": 13020,
    "endms": 15000,
    "text": "I'll start with an\noverview of what exactly"
  },
  {
    "startms": 15000,
    "endms": 17090,
    "text": "a relational database is and\nhow its structure differs"
  },
  {
    "startms": 17090,
    "endms": 18070,
    "text": "from the spreadsheets"
  },
  {
    "startms": 18070,
    "endms": 20030,
    "text": "that you might be used to working with."
  },
  {
    "startms": 20030,
    "endms": 22030,
    "text": "And I'll outline some of\nthe hidden difficulties"
  },
  {
    "startms": 22030,
    "endms": 24010,
    "text": "that can arise if the\nstructure of your data"
  },
  {
    "startms": 24010,
    "endms": 27020,
    "text": "isn't fully considered\nbefore development begins."
  },
  {
    "startms": 27020,
    "endms": 30000,
    "text": "Then we'll discover the\ndatabase development lifecycle"
  },
  {
    "startms": 30000,
    "endms": 32050,
    "text": "and use it as a guide for\nmoving through the process"
  },
  {
    "startms": 32050,
    "endms": 35040,
    "text": "of thinking about our\nspecific data storage needs."
  },
  {
    "startms": 35040,
    "endms": 36090,
    "text": "Finally, we'll talk about all of the rules"
  },
  {
    "startms": 36090,
    "endms": 38060,
    "text": "that we've identified\nabout how the database"
  },
  {
    "startms": 38060,
    "endms": 40060,
    "text": "needs to function and\nstart translating them"
  },
  {
    "startms": 40060,
    "endms": 41090,
    "text": "into the components that will make up"
  },
  {
    "startms": 41090,
    "endms": 44020,
    "text": "the actual relational database."
  },
  {
    "startms": 44020,
    "endms": 46050,
    "text": "And along the way, we'll\ndiscuss design considerations"
  },
  {
    "startms": 46050,
    "endms": 48030,
    "text": "that'll make the database\neasier to construct"
  },
  {
    "startms": 48030,
    "endms": 50050,
    "text": "and easier to maintain."
  },
  {
    "startms": 50050,
    "endms": 52000,
    "text": "So I'd like to thank you for joining me"
  },
  {
    "startms": 52000,
    "endms": 53070,
    "text": "in learning relational databases."
  },
  {
    "startms": 53070,
    "endms": 55040,
    "text": "Now let's get started."
  }
]
)

function animate(chunks) {
  chunks.forEach(({ startms, endms, text }) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.clear()
      console.log(text)
    }, startms)
  })
}
```

All I am doing is showing the text ***approximately*** when it is time to. But that is the problem, it is *approximate*. If there is any lag in the audio, then everything will get thrown off.

How can I make this animate the text properly *when the corresponding audio plays*? Say I just do:

```
var audio = new Audio('audio_file.mp3')
audio.play()
```

How do I sync the SRT with such an audio file?

It's not so straightforward that I can just hardcode or embed the SRT file directly into the audio file or show subtitles type of thing. I need to run custom animations on text and allow user interaction with the text while it is being spoken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <style>
      html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 800px;
        width: 800px;
      }

      @font-face {
        font-family: Tone;
        src: url('font.otf');
      }

      #content {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #000;
      }

      #row {
        font-size: 92px;
        font-family: Tone;
        width: 600px;
        text-align: center;
      }

      #row * {
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        color: #9A7FAE;
      }

      #row .highlight {
        color: #BEE5B0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='content'><div id='row'><span>`ԀŰ ĀӢŀÐА ÐàӢðԀ ŰԀ 0ѰВÐàԀ$ àԀ`Őϰŀ`Őђŀ`Ӡ ѰŰ ÐƐВŰӠ!</span></div></div>
    <script>
      const TIMED = [
  {
    "startms": 599,
    "endms": 2980,
    "text": "`ԀŰ ĀӢŀÐА ÐàӢðԀ ŰԀ 0ѰВÐàԀ$"
  },
  {
    "startms": 2980,
    "endms": 4848,
    "text": "àԀ`Őϰŀ`Őђŀ`Ӡ ѰŰ ÐƐВŰӠ!"
  },
  {
    "startms": 5563,
    "endms": 7932,
    "text": "Ѱŀ ŀВpϰŀ ŰϰӢİӠ pϲŰԀ ÐВààԀ"
  },
  {
    "startms": 7932,
    "endms": 12480,
    "text": "pђŀÐѰ `ВŰŰԀ ŀԀÐϲàԀ ѰŰ 0ӠÐВàА 0ԀƠԀŰŰВŰӠ!"
  },
  {
    "startms": 12480,
    "endms": 14974,
    "text": "PӠŀ ѰŰ ÐƐВŰӠ PӠѲ ðѰÐƐѲŀӠ$"
  },
  {
    "startms": 14974,
    "endms": 16152,
    "text": "0ϲӠѰ ðА`ВàА$"
  },
  {
    "startms": 16152,
    "endms": 17644,
    "text": "ÐӠPPԂàА$"
  },
  {
    "startms": 17644,
    "endms": 18658,
    "text": "pѐŀÐѲàА!"
  },
  {
    "startms": 19461,
    "endms": 23907,
    "text": "ŰԀ ÐϰԀ АŀѐƠ`ŐѲԀ ԂŰŰԀ 0ѰВÐàԀ Ѱŀ ÀàВÐÐԀ `ђðѰ ӠÀàѲàА!"
  },
  {
    "startms": 23907,
    "endms": 25125,
    "text": "ŰԀ ĀӠŀÐԂŀƀԀ"
  },
  {
    "startms": 25125,
    "endms": 27500,
    "text": "PӠŀpђàðԀ ŰԀ pϲԀ ÀӢàĀԀ$"
  },
  {
    "startms": 27500,
    "endms": 30118,
    "text": "PӢĀА ϲŀԀ 0ԂŰŰԀ pАİàВÐԀ!"
  },
  {
    "startms": 30448,
    "endms": 33103,
    "text": "ӠàԀ Ðϰ PӠŀÐàӢŰŰѰ ŰԀ 0ѰВÐàԀ$"
  },
  {
    "startms": 33103,
    "endms": 34930,
    "text": "àАԀŰѲÐԀ$"
  },
  {
    "startms": 34930,
    "endms": 36543,
    "text": "ӠppВàðԀ!"
  },
  {
    "startms": 36543,
    "endms": 38522,
    "text": "0ӠàÐԂŀ`ӠÐѰ ŀАŰ ÐƐВŰӠ$"
  },
  {
    "startms": 38522,
    "endms": 40656,
    "text": "ðђàpӠ ŰԀ İàԀŀ`ВÐԀ"
  },
  {
    "startms": 40656,
    "endms": 42565,
    "text": "ŰԀ pÐàԂ`Ԁ ВàÐԀ!"
  },
  {
    "startms": 42565,
    "endms": 45582,
    "text": "PӠpÐàϰѲƐѰ ÐƐѰӢ PА ðϲӠѰ$"
  },
  {
    "startms": 45582,
    "endms": 47607,
    "text": "PӠѲ PА ѰŰ ĀӢŀ`Ӡ ðВ`Ԁ!"
  },
  {
    "startms": 47607,
    "endms": 49113,
    "text": "Ӡ ŀВŰŰԀ ÐϲԀ ĀԂŀӠ$"
  },
  {
    "startms": 49113,
    "endms": 51704,
    "text": "0ѐƠ pѰPϰàВÐԀ àѰpѰВ`Ԁ!"
  },
  {
    "startms": 52817,
    "endms": 54553,
    "text": "ŰԀ 0ѰВÐàԀ Ѱ ŰԀ PѰԂðА$"
  },
  {
    "startms": 54553,
    "endms": 56769,
    "text": "PА Ԃ0àА ӢİŀѰ PӢԀ!"
  }
]

const TEXT = [
  '`ԀŰ ĀӢŀÐА ÐàӢðԀ ŰԀ 0ѰВÐàԀ$ àԀ`Őϰŀ`Őђŀ`Ӡ ѰŰ ÐƐВŰӠ!',
  'Ѱŀ ŀВpϰŀ ŰϰӢİӠ pϲŰԀ ÐВààԀ pђŀÐѰ `ВŰŰԀ ŀԀÐϲàԀ ѰŰ 0ӠÐВàА 0ԀƠԀŰŰВŰӠ!',
  'PӠŀ ѰŰ ÐƐВŰӠ PӠѲ ðѰÐƐѲŀӠ$ 0ϲӠѰ ðА`ВàА$ ÐӠPPԂàА$ pѐŀÐѲàА!',
  'ŰԀ ÐϰԀ АŀѐƠ`ŐѲԀ ԂŰŰԀ 0ѰВÐàԀ Ѱŀ ÀàВÐÐԀ `ђðѰ ӠÀàѲàА!',
  'ŰԀ ĀӠŀÐԂŀƀԀ PӠŀpђàðԀ ŰԀ pϲԀ ÀӢàĀԀ$ PӢĀА ϲŀԀ 0ԂŰŰԀ pАİàВÐԀ!',
  '',
  'ӠàԀ Ðϰ PӠŀÐàӢŰŰѰ ŰԀ 0ѰВÐàԀ$ àАԀŰѲÐԀ$ ӠppВàðԀ!',
  '0ӠàÐԂŀ`ӠÐѰ ŀАŰ ÐƐВŰӠ$ ðђàpӠ ŰԀ İàԀŀ`ВÐԀ ŰԀ pÐàԂ`Ԁ ВàÐԀ!',
  'PӠpÐàϰѲƐѰ ÐƐѰӢ PА ðϲӠѰ$ PӠѲ PА ѰŰ ĀӢŀ`Ӡ ðВ`Ԁ!',
  'Ӡ ŀВŰŰԀ ÐϲԀ ĀԂŀӠ$ 0ѐƠ pѰPϰàВÐԀ àѰpѰВ`Ԁ!',
  'ŰԀ 0ѰВÐàԀ Ѱ ŰԀ PѰԂðА$ PА Ԃ0àА ӢİŀѰ PӢԀ!',
]

    window.addEventListener('click', start)

    function start() {
      const audio = new Audio('it.wav')
      audio.play()
      let start = Date.now()
      update()

      function update() {
        const now = Date.now()
        const elapsedTime = now - start
        const next = TIMED[0]
        if (next.startms <= elapsedTime) {
          TIMED.shift()
          show(next.text)
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(update)
      }

      function find(text) {
        for (let i = 0, n = TEXT.length; i < n; i++) {
          let line = TEXT[i]
          let index = line.indexOf(text)
          if (index > -1) {
            let left = line.substr(0, index)
            let center = line.substr(index, text.length)
            let right = line.substr(index + text.length)
            return { left, center, right, i }
          }
        }
        return {}
      }

      function show(text) {
        const { left, center, right, i } = find(text)
        if (!center) return

        const l = `<span>${left}</span>`
        const c = `<span class='highlight'>${center}</span>`
        const r = `<span>${right}</span>`

        let container = document.querySelector('#row')
        container.innerHTML = `${l}${c}${r}`
      }
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```